# Quercus on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, quercus

I have added Quercus wrongly on google app engine and it is giving me errors.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>QueAttempt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.que.attempt.QueAttemptServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>QueAttempt</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/queattempt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>


   <init-param>
     <param-name>license-directory</param-name>
     <param-value>WEB-INF/licenses</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>



</web-app>
```

This is my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application></application>
<version>1</version>


 <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>


 <system-properties>
<property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
```

```
  <static-files>
    <include path="/**" expiration="600s" />
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="30d" />
    <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="30d" />
    <include path="/**.gif" expiration="30d" />
    <include path="/**.ico" expiration="30d" />
    <include path="/**.swf" expiration="30d" />
    <include path="/**.css" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="2d 12h" />
    <exclude path="/**.php" />
    <exclude path="/**.inc" />
  </static-files>

  <resource-files>
    <include path="/**.php" />
    <include path="/**.inc" />
  </resource-files>

</appengine-web-app>
```

For the files in quercus-4.0.25\WEB-INF\lib, I manually copy and paste them to

C:\QueAttempt\war\WEB-INF\lib.

With all of these done, I visit the app on localhost and there is an error message.

The webpage shows one line of error which is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.caucho.util.Alarm
```

The error shown on the console is:

```
WARNING: Error for /
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at   com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at com.caucho.quercus.page.PageManager.<init>(PageManager.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.createPageManager(QuercusContext.java:380)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.<init>(QuercusContext.java:250)
at com.caucho.quercus.GoogleQuercus.<init>(GoogleQuercus.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.GoogleQuercusServletImpl.getQuercus(GoogleQuercusServletImpl.java:279)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServletImpl.init(QuercusServletImpl.java:89)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.initImpl(QuercusServlet.java:531)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.init(QuercusServlet.java:441)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:247)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:224)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.maybeServeWelcomeFile(StaticFileFilter.java:197)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:277)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.startWorkerThread(ThreadLauncher.java:125)
at com.caucho.env.thread.AbstractTaskWorker.wake(AbstractTaskWorker.java:118)
at com.caucho.env.thread.AbstractThreadLauncher.update(AbstractThreadLauncher.java:453)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.setPriorityIdleMin(ThreadLauncher.java:74)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.<init>(ThreadLauncher.java:64)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:136)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:129)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.getThreadPool(ThreadPool.java:156)
at com.caucho.util.AlarmClock.<init>(AlarmClock.java:65)
at com.caucho.util.Alarm.<clinit>(Alarm.java:68)
... 63 more
May 23, 2012 11:36:27 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:277)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.startWorkerThread(ThreadLauncher.java:125)
at com.caucho.env.thread.AbstractTaskWorker.wake(AbstractTaskWorker.java:118)
at com.caucho.env.thread.AbstractThreadLauncher.update(AbstractThreadLauncher.java:453)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.setPriorityIdleMin(ThreadLauncher.java:74)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadLauncher.<init>(ThreadLauncher.java:64)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:136)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:129)
at com.caucho.env.thread.ThreadPool.getThreadPool(ThreadPool.java:156)
at com.caucho.util.AlarmClock.<init>(AlarmClock.java:65)
at com.caucho.util.Alarm.<clinit>(Alarm.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at com.caucho.quercus.page.PageManager.<init>(PageManager.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.createPageManager(QuercusContext.java:380)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.<init>(QuercusContext.java:250)
at com.caucho.quercus.GoogleQuercus.<init>(GoogleQuercus.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.GoogleQuercusServletImpl.getQuercus(GoogleQuercusServletImpl.java:279)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServletImpl.init(QuercusServletImpl.java:89)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.initImpl(QuercusServlet.java:531)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.init(QuercusServlet.java:441)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:247)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:224)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.maybeServeWelcomeFile(StaticFileFilter.java:197)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
May 23, 2012 11:36:32 AM com.caucho.quercus.servlet.GoogleQuercusServletImpl service
WARNING: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.caucho.util.Alarm
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.caucho.util.Alarm
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at com.caucho.quercus.page.PageManager.<init>(PageManager.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.createPageManager(QuercusContext.java:380)
at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.<init>(QuercusContext.java:250)
at com.caucho.quercus.GoogleQuercus.<init>(GoogleQuercus.java:61)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.GoogleQuercusServletImpl.getQuercus(GoogleQuercusServletImpl.java:279)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.GoogleQuercusServletImpl.service(GoogleQuercusServletImpl.java:154)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.service(QuercusServlet.java:594)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:247)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:224)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.maybeServeWelcomeFile(StaticFileFilter.java:197)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?  You should be using the latest version (4.0.30, resin.jar from resin-4.0.30/lib).